# Vector Equation of Straight Line

Tags: vectors

I have a question related to vector equation of straight line.

Taking $O$ as origin, the straight line $L$ has the vector equation
$$\overrightarrow{r}=2\hat{i}+\hat{j}-\hat{k}+\lambda\left(-\hat{i}+3\hat{j}+\hat{k}\right)$$
The point $Q$ lies on $L$ such that $\overrightarrow{OQ}$ is perpendicular to $L$.  We need to find the coordinates of $Q$.

I understand that the dot product of $\overrightarrow{OQ}$ and the direction vector is $0$.  This gives only one equation in terms of $x, y,z$. How can we get $\left(x,y,z\right)$.

Comment: That one equation in $x_Q,y_Q,z_Q$ is actually one equation in $\lambda_Q$ (since $Q$ lies on $L$) so you can solve it for $\lambda_Q$ and hence the coordinates of $Q$.

Comment: To drive home user10354138's point, look at your problem statement. There are no variables $x, y,$ or $z$ defined in it. There is only a variable $\lambda$. The dot product will be in terms of $\lambda$, not "$x, y, z$".